# angular 2 with spring security 404 error tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-security

angular2 app working as a standalone in tomcat in root as well as in context path.
I am integrating with app in the spring Rest back end using the plugin

```
<plugin> <!-- Jagruti -->
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-resources</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/static</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/web/dist/</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

War is prepared, deployed on tomcat server, it says 404 page not found.
I have spring security allowing all the paths

```
enter code here     http
              .exceptionHandling()
              .and()
              .headers().cacheControl();


      http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).permitAll()
              .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).permitAll().and()
```

I am pretty sure that is is spring disabling the index.html page
Web.xml has welcome file list , set to index.html
I tried commenting out @EnableWebSecurity, but no joy. 
Where am I am going wrong?
I tried all other authorizerequest, antmapper to /** but no joy, tried with csrf filter, enabling csrf , but csrf shouldnt matter as it is from one war  file.
I  am out of options.

Any light on this please?
When I remove the classes folder, angular 2 app works, so I am sure it is spring.

Appreciate help on this please?
Jagruti

Comment: "angular2 app working as a standalone in tomcat" means that spring is serving your Angular2 app? First, check in the war is the app has been copied properly!

Comment: app working as standalone- means dist folder copied to root folder in tomcat- Works

Comment: Yes , when war is deployed in tomcat  apache-tomcat-8.0.27\webapps\ecsWEB-INF\classes\static, dist files are there, this means it is being copied correctly.

Comment: thanks nano for your interest

Comment: eventhough it is copied correctly on folder it doesnt renders, gives 404

Comment: i suspect it can be related to context path, but not sure how to set it

Comment: <base href="/"> might be causing

Comment: Delete @EnableWebMvc annotation if you have any. It overrides the default properties of Spring Mvc, including the default static folder exposure.